# Why is this usage of setjmp/longjmp undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, setjmp

### The code

```
#include <csetjmp>

template <typename Callable>
void create_checkpoint(std::jmp_buf buf, Callable&& callable)
{
    if (setjmp(buf) != 0)
    {
        callable();
    }
}

#include <iostream>

struct announcer {
    int id;
    announcer(int id):
        id{id}
    {
        std::cout << "created announcer with id " << id << '\n';
    }
    ~announcer() {
        std::cout << "destructing announcer with id " << id << '\n'; 
    }
};

void oopsie(std::jmp_buf buf, bool shouldJump)
{
    if (shouldJump)
    {
        // std::cout << "performing jump...\n";
        std::longjmp(buf, 1);
    }
}

void test1() 
{
    std::jmp_buf buf;
    announcer a1{1};
    create_checkpoint(buf, []() {throw std::exception();});
    oopsie(buf, true);
}

void test2()
{
    std::jmp_buf buf;
    announcer a1{1};
    create_checkpoint(buf, []() {throw std::exception();});
    oopsie(buf, false);


    announcer a2{2};
    create_checkpoint(buf, []() {throw std::exception();});
    oopsie(buf, true);
}

int main()
{
    try 
    {
        test1();
    }
    catch (...)
    {}

    try 
    {
        test2();
    }
    catch (...)
    {}
}
```

### Context

I have to call some C library that reports errors via `longjmp`. To provide strong exception guarantee, I want to create a function that is very similar to `std::lock_guard`, e.g. I just write `create_checkpoint(buf, handler)` and keep calling the C library functions until I allocate more resources (destructors for objects created below `setjmp` line are not called, if I understand correctly).

### Question

Why undefined behavior is invoked in this case and how can I fix it?

### How did I find out this is undefined behavior?

[Printing message to `std::cout`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gVqNECcoITHe2l8C) before `std::longjmp` vs [not printing](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Az0eSCKKsnO1641e) produces very different results even though that line has little to do with control flow.

### What do I understand by now?

I understand that `std::longjmp` essentially restores the registers and jumps at the instruction pointer saved by `setjmp` macro. Also, [functions are not optimized away](https://godbolt.org/z/rKqhQG), and at least during compilation, there is an instruction to call `longjmp`.

Converting the `create_checkpoint` to macro [seems to solve the issue](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vNFz3A6sND5Nvo9W). Yet I wonder is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Any use of `setjmp`/`longjmp` in modern C++ should be *HEAVILY* discouraged. In fact, I'd consider any use a signal that the code in question should *never* be merged into the main code base.

Comment: `longjmp` bypasses C++ stack unwinding, so destructors are not called.  You fix it by either not using `longjmp`, or carefully catch each one as close to the part of the code that invokes it and convert it to an exception or handle it appropriately.  Also note that `setjmp`/`longjmp` do not restore non-volatile variables at the `setjmp` location, so they are not trustworthy to be properly accounted for in the handler.

Comment: I should mention, I've maintained a very large program that used `setjmp`/`longjmp` extensively.  I strongly discourage using them in a C++ program, with every fiber of my being.  They are the nuclear equivalent of `goto`.

Comment: @Eljay, unfortunately in one of the cases it seems like it is unavoidable (libjpeg). We do not know if the whole call tree is correctly covered, so I thought having a guard function would be nice. Macro seems to solve the problem, but I am not sure if it is the right way forward.

Comment: Please vote for deletion if you think the question is useless.

Comment: I think this a good question.  It's something C++ inherited from C, but can cause lots of grief if used in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/longjmp

> If the function that called setjmp has exited, the behavior is undefined (in other words, only long jumps up the call stack are allowed)

As you aren't following this rule your program has undefined behaviour

Comment: I see. So only macro can be created, and not a function? Would it be possible to somehow inline the function? Also, should I delete the question? It seems rather useless now.

Comment: Yep, a macro could probably do the job. No need to delete the question, someone else will likely have a similar question in the future

Answer (score 2):

Code that populates a `jmp_buff` has to know what should be on left on the stack after it is passed to `longjmp`.  If `setjmp` were processed as a compiler intrinsic that was only usable within a function that return `int`, the compiler could arrange things so that `longjmp` would cause the function that called `setjmp` to "return twice", rather than treating the `setjmp` itself as doing so.  On many implementations, however, calls to `setjmp` are processed just like any other calls to functions about which the compiler's knowledge is limited to the prototype.  On such implementations, there would be no way for `setjmp` to arrange to have the `longjmp` return to the calling function's caller without information about that function's stack frame.  While the compiler processing the `setjmp` call would have the needed information, it would have no reason to make it available to `setjmp`, and `setjmp` would have no way of getting the information without such compiler support.

BTW, what's more vexing about `setjmp` is that while it's possible for it to return a value, `setjmp` calls must appear within a very narrow set of contexts, none of which can conveniently capture the value returned.  One could in theory say:

```
int setJmpValue;
switch(setjmp(...))
{
  case 0: setJmpValue=0; break;
  case 1: setJmpValue=1; break;
  ...
  case INT_MAX-1: setJmpValue = INT_MAX-1; break;
  case INT_MAX  : setJmpValue = INT_MAX  ; break;
}
```

but that would be rather annoying and could not be exported to a function.

I don't think there should be any difficulty with allowing `i = setJmp(...);` where `i` is an `int` of either static or automatic duration, and that would in turn make possible any arbitrary use of the returned value, but no such construct is provided for in the Standard, and it is no longer fashionable for compilers to process useful constructs predictably except when the Standard compels them to do so.